# Sort a list according to another list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

In Python, how can we sort **array #2**, according to **array #1**. What I mean is that **array #1** is the reference.

This is sorted, according to some previous comparaison I did. It acts as a reference let's say:

**array #1**: [5, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2]

Now, **array #2** contains the following:
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

How can we sort **#2** so that it becomes:
[5, 1, 4, 6, 2]

** EDIT **:

**Array #2**: We can't know if it will be the same size as **#1**, but it will always be as big, or smaller. It will always be a subset of **Array #1**.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want this to do, particularly when the array isn't exactly the same? If the second array IS always the same, why do this it all?

Comment: You example is a bit unclear. Is arr2 always a subset of arr1?

Comment: Your question is unclear, are your talking about python `list` or `numpy.array`?

Comment: See edit. Also, it's a list. Yes sorry

Comment: Well, then `[x for x in a1 if x in a2]` gives you what you want.

Comment: Do you walso want to sort `[1,1,5,5]` into `[5,5,1,1]`?

Comment: DSM, I should have said they are unique! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the items in `arr2` to appear in the same order as they appear in `arr1`. So it is natural that you would want to iterate through `arr1` and select those items which are members of `arr2`. Checking membership is more efficiently done with a set, so first compute `set2`, and then select items from `arr1` that are in `set2`:

```
In [16]: set2 = set(arr2)

In [17]: [item for item in arr1 if item in set2]
Out[17]: [5, 1, 4, 6, 2]
```

---

Per the comments, here is a [timeit benchmark](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions) (using [IPython](http://ipython.org/)) which shows that using a set is faster than using a list:

```
In [20]: import random

In [21]: arr1 = range(20)

In [22]: random.shuffle(arr1)

In [23]: arr2 = random.sample(arr1, len(arr1)-1)

In [25]: %timeit set2 = set(arr2); [item for item in arr1 if item in set2]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.13 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit [item for item in arr1 if item in arr2]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.49 µs per loop
```

Comment: I presume on a large list it is faster?

Comment: Clean and simple! Thanks :)!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, for large lists this will be much faster (linear versus quadratic complexity). Checking membership in a set is `O(1)`, while checking membership in a list is `O(n)`. The above is `O(n) + O(m)`, where `n = len(arr1)`, `m = len(arr2)`. If you check membership in the list `arr2` instead of the set `set2`, then the code would be `O(n*m)`.

Comment: @unutbu, cool. I realised that after I wrote it. What sort of numbers are we talking before there is a noticeable difference?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Well, that could depend on a number of factors (in other words, it pays to benchmark this for yourself, for a variety of data), but I'm seeing 2x speedup using a set over a list when `n, m = 20, 19`. I'll post my method of benchmarking above.

Comment: @unutbu, I did some tests on smaller input but it will be interesting to see your results. Does using range influence then timeit results?